# show value if today is equal to or less then two weeks away php

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to *show* the value startdate (value set in DB) if *today is greater then or equal 2 weeks away* then if value enddate (value set in DB) *is equal to or greater then today hide the value.*

So far I have:

```
$dateintwoweeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');

$dateintwoweeks = date("H:i:s:T");

if ( $dateintwoweeks >=  $startdate) {

echo "Upcoming: {$startdate}";
```

I am not sure if I am on the right track or way off but I am not sure how I would complete the second part on hiding the value if enddate >+ today.

Comment: `strtotime($db_value) >= time()` -> hide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
// get `time` of two weeks
$dateintwoweeks = strtotime('+2 weeks');
// convert string date to `time`
$timeStartDate = strtotime($startdate);
// check if `time` of two weeks greater than `startdate`
if ( $dateintwoweeks >=  $startdate) {
    echo "Upcoming: {$startdate}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically u can do the same in mysql as-well
 by using DATEDIFF(expr1,expr2) it returns a number .

```
SELECT startdate,enddate,DATEDIFF(startdate,enddate) from tableName
```